# How do I prevent Whatsapp displaying entries in the contacts app?

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger

Whatsapp is creating duplicate contacts on my Android phone. I know that the duplicates belong to Whatsapp because:

1. I have checked the Android contacts storage database, which confirms the duplicates come from Whatsapp and
2. By going to Settings > Users & accounts and deleting WhatsApp, all of these duplicate contacts are gone. They re-appear when I restart WhatsApp.

The prevailing wisdom (e.g. [this answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/133455/254773)) is that to rectify this issue just go to the contacts app, click on the three dots, select "Contacts to Display", and deselect Whatsapp. However, when I do this, I select "Customised view", but Whatsapp does not appear in the list of accounts which I can show or hide.

Is there any other way to hide Whatsapp's contact list from within the default Android contacts app?

Things I would rather avoid:

1. Revoking contacts permissions for Whatsapp. If I do that, I won't be able to see the names of contacts any more from inside Whatsapp.
2. Using a different contacts app. This is just avoiding the issue, rather than trying to fix it.

The phone is a Xiaomi Mi A1, and the OS is Android One, version 8.0.

Comment: In your contacts app settings go to 'contacts to display' and press on 'customized view'. Now you should able to select which ones to display and which ones not to. Let me know if that's how it is in your phone, and I'll post as an answer.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I already tried that, but Whatsapp doesn't appear in the list. I edited the answer to make this clear.