# Dialer & Contacts app display duplicate (WhatsApp)

Tags: contacts, whatsapp-messenger, phone-app, google-contacts

**Issue**: When searching in dialer or contacts apps (From Google Play store, latest version) many contacts show up twice. Only contacts with WhatsApp (or more times if more phone numbers stored under the contact have WhatsApp enable)

https://contacts.google.com online show only one Contact. So no "real" duplicates.

**Manual Fix, (one by one):** When I edit & save the contact the contacts are now "merged" like it used to be.

This is a new phone and WhatsApp data was restored from Cloud backup.

Same issue:

- [WhatsApp contacts doesn't merge with Google Contacts](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/130943/55984)
- [Exact same contact shown twice](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/133285/55984)
- https://github.com/WhisperSystems/Signal-Android/issues/4191
- https://forum.xda-developers.com/2015-moto-g/help/contact-duplication-phone-dialer-app-t3662691
- https://forum.xda-developers.com/galaxy-s6/help/duplicate-dialer-t3182676

**Attempts to fix**

- Customize the view in contacts app is not a solutions.
- Cleared the Contacts Storage data

Any suggestion how to fix it without manual touching all contacts?

Comment: Is there no option in the app similar to "manage similar contacts"? Samsung phone have that option in the menu and that mergers the contacts together without having to do it manually

Comment: the Google Contact apps doesn't have that. Also these are not "real" duplicates, otherwise I could find and merge online in my desktop browser at [contacts.google.com](https://contacts.google.com)

Comment: What about an option in your contacts app settings, to just display your Google contacts? I don't have the same app so i can't test this

Answer (score 1):

I solved this issue by editing all my Google contacts to make sure they contain full country code and no dashes or spaces between the numbers. In the Google Contacts landing page (web) they will all look OK but once you click edit you might find some with the incorrect format. Doing this will enable the Dialer app to link the mobile and Whats App contacts correctly. I know this is still a tedious manual fix but it is the only one I found to work.

Answer (score 1):

Expected the same behaviour like in the question above. Duplicate entries (for each messenger/linked data contact) while searching, distinct entries in the normal list view.

I failed on so many tries and tried to solve it and therefore would like to share a very messy but still pretty failsafe variant for this (at least I think it is).

1. Open https://contacts.google.com/
2. Export the data for fail-safety (had chosen Google CSV)
3. Add all data to a new label (or  might be called group) with a name like "old ones"
4. Import this downloaded data afterwards. There should be a new label (or group) with the imported data

**Variant A (more unsafe, worked for me):**

5. Then I merged all duplicate contacts
6. All contacts showed the linked data directly and searching showed distinct results

**Variant B (not tried, but should be working well and safe):**

5. Check out that your synchronized contacts that work will show up with the newly imported label. I do not know if this will work because I do not know if more than one contact can be associated with a whatsapp profile...
6. Either merge or delete the old contacts
7. Result untested like said

**System**

- Android 9 (Android One)
- Phone: Mi A2 Lite
- Setup about one week before

Hope this helps since like youre approach by saving every contact all over.

Greetings

**EDIT1** One important note. Every user that was imported in the variant A has now an addition field containing the image url of this user (the images were still present, might be some merge conflict so deleting the old ones could be better)

**EDIT2** In my case, exporting and importing without merging will loose all contact images although they are listed in the exported file... (thanks!).
With Variant A you will still have theses images but an additional "Photo" field in the contact that stores the image url (can be managed in the contacts list on your computers browser)

Answer (score 0):

I solved by giving all the permissions to the contacts/dialer app. Probably one of those solved the issue.