# Contacts displayed multiples times with different color codings

Tags: stock-android, 9.0-pie, xiaomi, google-contacts

Today, I migrated to a new cell phone running Android Pie. The model of the phone is Xiaomi Mi A3. I use to back up all my contacts on Google Contacts and sync it whenever I change my phone. This time, I ran into an issue. Though each contact is saved exactly once in Google Contacts/Contacts App, I find multiple copies of each contact displayed in my Phone App with different "color codings". I assume the colors represent something which I have no idea about.

Kindly suggest a way to get this resolved. Thanks!

[image: A snapshot of the list of displayed contacts]

Comment: In the app's settings, check which contacts are displayed. It is quite possible that all contacts form your sim card, Google account and other are displayed. If you only your Google account if you only want to view those contacts.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio I checked. There are no saved contacts in my SIM card. And the only account where all my contacts are synced is on Google's. Moreover, I don't even see an option to merge duplicate contacts on my phone, if there are duplicates present.

Comment: What happened when you view the contacts via the phone app, then via the contacts app? Do both apps show duplicates? Note that I said Phone app and Contacts app.

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Phone app is showing duplicate contacts, each with a different color coding. It seems that they are the contacts automatically created by the system. Contacts app is showing no duplicates.

Comment: See if this [question](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/187886/dialer-contacts-app-display-duplicate-whatsapp) helps. If not, click each duplicate and try to see if numbers are different, check if the location (storage) is different, etc.